# Can the plumbing for a shower/tub combo be put in the wall between the house and the garage?

Tags: plumbing, walls

Specifically, what matters is if it's considered an interior or exterior wall? In building our home, we were told the shower faucet could not be on that end because it was an exterior wall.
The only information I have found is that if plumbing is on an exterior wall, it has to be better insulated.

Comment: Somebody around here mentioned those European shower box things the other day. Have you considered moving the waterlines to the interior side of the wall? Something like the picture with the valve at https://www.amazon.com/Installation-Exposed-Outdoor-Thermostatic-Convert/dp/B07DLX7LLC/. You might ask a new question about surface mounting options if you're interested.

Comment: It's the fourth image in the main carousel of images at the top.

Comment: Please revise to provide more information about your location, climate, insulation, garage heat, etc. The question isn't answerable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Plumbing codes get written by large institutions, but localities frequently override parts, typically making more difficult constraints. Rummaging through Indiana's overrides a while back, I recall that waterlines in exterior walls are forbidden. You could live in a locality with such a constraint. Insulating the garage would relieve the constraint.

[There it is](https://www.in.gov/dhs/files/Section-305.6.1-Installation-of-water-lines-in-unconditioned-spaces.pdf) again:

> No waterlines shall be concealed in outside walls, above grade.